# Delayed payment using Authorize.net's iframe to collect payment information

Tags: authorize.net

We occasionally allow our customers to purchase our product and delay the payment until a pre-determined date. In order to do this, we need to collect the payment information at the time the order is placed. We are using the iframe method of collecting payment information.

I imagine I can use ARB to set up a one-time payment that will be billed at a specific date. However, that only works if I have the payment information stored away in a profile to begin with.

How can I collect the user's payment information without an initial charge, so that I can set up a payment at a later date?

Comment: No matter what you do, you need to capture the user's payment data up front. But you don't need to charge it until you're ready. Without it you can't ever charge that payment. In Authnet's case, you can create one recurring payment at a future date or create a payment profile and then run a charge against that profile at a future date.

Comment: Creating a recurring payment requires a pre-existing payment profile though, doesn't it? We don't have that yet for our customers. Is there a way to get payment information via an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by John Conde, there is a hosted form that will allow you to collect payment information. It supports iFrame. You can create a customer profile first and then initiate this form. There are options to verify the card information or defer it to later, depending on your requirements.

You can find documentation in the link below. Search for "GetHostedProfilePage"

https://www.authorize.net/content/dam/anet-redesign/documents/CIM_SOAP_guide.pdf

Comment: I will look into this, but I'm not using the hosted payment page - I am using the iframe method to collect payment information. I don't expect that this will meet our requirements.

Comment: The Authorize.net hosted pages have an option to display the hosted page in an iframe on your website. My mistake. I assumed that was what you were using. There are a number of APIs that will let you create payment methods. You can view them at https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles. Good luck with your project.